# How to optimize code parser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python, and just started to learn the principles of object oriented Programming, this does not judge strictly.
This code is fully working but confused some elements:

1) I dont anderstend what needs to return **init**
2) I do not like so much `self.` in `def get_parse():`

Initially, I did it in order to be able to easily cause Parse.id or you want me to attribute

But now, I need to first create an instance of the class, and then call the function `get_parse` while accepting self and the number of lines (`k`), and only then, I will be available for items such as `Parse.title`

I tried to do the same when declaring **init**, but nothing came of it, because at this stage the function may not be available (this is especially the language, is not it? In IPython not exist, or am I mistaken too?)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import csv

class Parse:

    k = 1

    def __init__(self,k):
        pass


    def read_csv(k):
        with open('/home/narnikgamarnik/PycharmProjects/my_phyton3_projects/products_links2.csv') as f:
            r = csv.reader(f)
            cont = [row for row in r]
            d = (cont[k])[0]
            return d


    def get_url(d):
        try:
            url = urllib.request.urlopen(d)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            if err.code == 404:
                return False
            else:
                raise
        return url


    def get_title(url):
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
            ol = soup.find('ol', 'breadcrumb')
            title = ol.find_all('li')[-1].string
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        return title

    def get_gender(url):
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
            ol = soup.find('ol', 'breadcrumb')
            gender = ol.find_all('a')[0].string
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        return gender

    def get_category(url):
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
            ol = soup.find('ol', 'breadcrumb')
            brand = ol.find_all('a').get_text[1].string
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        return brand


    def get_model(url):
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
            ol = soup.find('ol', 'breadcrumb')
            model = ol.find_all('a')[2].string
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        return model


    def get_article(url):
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
            product_code = soup.find('p', 'product__code')
            article = product_code.find_all('span')[0].string
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        return article


    def get_article_2(url):
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
            geth1 = soup.find('h1')
            article_2 = geth1.find_all('span')[0].string
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        return article_2


    def get_prices(url):
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
            product_price = soup.find_all('span', 'select_currency currency hide')
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        return product_price


    def get_img(url):
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
            div = soup.find_all('div', 'fotorama fotorama-primary')
            for a in div:
                b = a.find_all('a')
                images = []
                for c in b:
                    d = c['data-full']
                    images.append(d)
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        return images


    def get_parse(self,k):
        self.d = self.read_csv(k)
        self.url = self.get_url(self.d)
        self.title = self.get_title(self.url)
        self.url = self.get_url(self.d)
        self.gender = self.get_gender(self.url)
        self.url = self.get_url(self.d)
        self.category = self.get_category(self.url)
        self.url = self.get_url(self.d)
        self.model = self.get_model(self.url)
        self.url = self.get_url(self.d)
        self.article = self.get_article(self.url)
        self.url = self.get_url(self.d)
        self.article_2 = self.get_article_2(self.url)
        self.url = self.get_url(self.d)
        self.prices = self.get_prices(self.url)
        self.price_pln = self.prices[0].string[3:6]
        self.price_usd = self.prices[1].string[3:6]
        self.price_eur = self.prices[2].string[3:6]
        self.price_gbp = self.prices[3].string[3:6]
        self.price_rub = self.prices[4].string[3:7]
        self.url = self.get_url(self.d)
        self.images = self.get_img(self.url)
        return self.d, self.title, self.gender, self.category, self.model, self.article, self.article_2, self.images, self.price_pln, self.price_usd, self.price_eur, self.price_gbp, self.price_rub, self.images
```

In any case, it is not a question of "choose me", but simply "consultation" with experienced programmers.
Thanks you!

Comment: Does your code work? If it does, you should check out [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). It's for improving/optimising working code. If your code _isn't_ working, you shouldn't be trying to prematurely optimise it.

Comment: my code works,
you can check :)

Thanks for the tip, I did not know about the existence of the service, a link to which you have thrown off

Comment: You're welcome. Welcome to stackexchange!